# windows.location.href changes while handelng MutationObserver mutation events

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, mutation-observers

I check links on a page using selenium and MutationObserver. One link that I know becomes present, is not matched, consistently. When the timeout occurs, window.location.href is different than the page's original location. How can that happen?

Running the javascript in a debugger (chrome) this doesn't happen, but also everything matches without getting to the point of creating the MutationObserver, in that case.

Comment: I'm confused, how is the MutationObserver and the link's `src` related to `location.href`?

Comment: It's not clear how the description is related to the Selenium. How do you create the mutation observers? Via script execution from Selenium? Please show us code. Keep in mind to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm not sure how revealing this will be. The code is evaluated by JavascriptExecutor.execAsyncScript which passes a callback to the javascript. That is the "selenium" parameter:

Comment: Arggh. I can't delete the other message apparently.


I'm not sure how revealing this will be. The code is evaluated by JavascriptExecutor.execAsyncScript which passes a callback to the javascript. That is the "selenium" parameter:


https://pastebin.com/s4cVVfD5


The result is that something like this appears in the console log:


Timeout orig(http://example.com/here) window orig=(http://example.com/there) document orig=(http://example.com/there)

Answer (score 0):

I left out a key detail which didn't occur to me, which is that it is only the hash that is changing (the URL fragment). For example:

http://exmaple.com/somewhere#here

becomes

http://exmaple.com/somewhere#there

So, this is normalish and there is no network traffic when the hash is changing.

I can create a window.onhashchange handler to do something appropriate when this happens.